# Heroku tutorial error running python manage.py syncdb to update local database

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heroku, python-2.7

This question has been asked before and answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11618800/error-when-running-python-manage-py-syncdb-locally-but-no-error-when-running), and I understand the reasoning as to why I am getting the error, however I am still unclear about the solution from the answer given. What code or changes should I be adding to make it work? Do I need to make changes to

```
 DATABASES['default'] =  dj_database_url.config()
```

in my settings? The tutorial isn't very clear about this.  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What ended up working eventually was to add:

```
import dj_database_url
DATABASES['default'] =  dj_database_url.config(default='postgres://<user>:<password>@localhost:5432/<name>')
```

instead of just

```
import dj_database_url
DATABASES['default'] =  dj_database_url.config()
```

like the tutorial states. Then when trying to run

```
python manage.py runserver
```

I still got the error

```
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

I then was able to figure out that the stickpeople build i needed to use was the 64 bit instead of the 32 bit that the tutorial had me use, and the 64 bit build is:

```
easy_install http://www.stickpeople.com/projects/python/win-psycopg/psycopg2-2.4.5.win-amd64-py2.7-pg9.1.3-release.exe
```

I don't know if it was the best way, but in order to use the 64 bit build I started over from the beginning.  Now it finally works.  Hopefully this can also be used to help anyone else who is also stuck.  There are a lot of holes in the heroku tutorial.

Comment: Really you shouldn't be hard coding the DATABASE_URL in your settings.py file. This is because these details will vary between environments such as development and production. They should be set via environment variables instead and then DATABASES['default'] =  dj_database_url.config() will work because it will find the definitions. See my comment to Will's answer for the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Either setup and use `virtualenv` with a DATABASE_URL config var, or run your program with `DATABASE_URL=postgres:///databasename <how you'd normally run your program>`

Comment: You should create a file named .env in your project home (i.e. next to PROCFILE) and add DATABASE_URL there (e.g. DATABASE_URL=postgres:///databasename). You should then run syndb through foreman with "foreman run python manage.py syncdb".  Foreman will then setup the environment variables before running the command.